# How to get color for column value based on value using ngx-datatable bootstrap-4

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4, colors, angular7, ngx-datatable

I want to get value with color for column based on value. I'm using bootstrap 4 ngx-datatable. I'm posting an image below, could you please let me know the solution for this[image]
typeScript :

```
 displayColumns = [
        { name: 'S.No', value: 'sno' }, { name: 'Order Type', value: 'orderType'},
        { name: 'Customer Name', value: 'partyName' }, { name: 'Customer City', value: 'hcncode' },
        { name: 'Order Date', value: 'billDate' },
       { name: 'Order Status', value: 'orderStatus' },
        { name: 'Actions' }
    ];
```

Html

```
  <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="invoiceSource" [headerHeight]="50"
                                    [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'50'" [scrollbarH]="true" 
                                    [columnMode]="'force'" [limit]="limit"
                                    [sorts]="[{prop: 'productCode', dir: 'asc'}]">
                                    <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of displayColumns"
                                        [name]="column.name">
                                        <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                                            <span>{{column.name}}</span>
                                        </ng-template>
                                        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex"  
                                            let-value="value" let-row="row">
                                            <span *ngIf="column.name !== 'Actions'">{{row[column.value]}}</span>
                                            <span *ngIf="column.name === 'Actions'">
                                                <button class="btn btn-success mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top" data-controls-modal=" " data-toggle="jw-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" 
                                                    ngbTooltip="View" (click)="SerachInvoice(row , 'custom-modal-2')">
                                                    <i class="ft-eye"></i>
                                                </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Edit"
                                                 (click)="edit(row)">
                                                <i class="ft-edit"></i>
                                              </button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-warning mr-1 btn-fab" placement="top"
                                                    ngbTooltip="Print" (click)="SerachInvoice(row,'printSection')">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </span>
                                        </ng-template>
                                    </ngx-datatable-column>
                                </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem?  i will surely help you

Comment: Hi Khalid khan im using ngx-datable. i have no of orders i need to show colors for order status column based on value(like above sceen exactly). if row of orderstatus colunm value  complte need to show with green color

Comment: above image requirement not implemented, so need to show exactly  above

Comment: Okay got it. Can you post datatable code part here ?

Comment: Khalid khan Can u look in to above datatable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208172/discussion-between-user2564537-and-khalid-khan).